# Should keeping the vanity url same as the original page url affect the sidekick workflow option?

Tags: aem

I am a beginner at CQ5. I created a simple workflow with 2 paths - accept and reject. I created a page and set its vanity url the same as the original page url and checked the "Redirect Vanity url" text box. Next I pushed the page down the workflow. But then when I opened up the page in the browser and clicked on the workflow tab of the sidekick, it was completely blank. Removing the vanity url brought back the workflow tab contents. Can someone explain to me why this happened so? This wasn't mapped in the ConfigMgr console.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the vanity url actual does something like a "Redirect". So if we add a vanity url to a page which has the same url as the vanity url, the page goes into something like an infinite loop, redirecting to itself. This causes trouble in various sorts. In my case, it was affecting the workflow.